# name of a distribution

Tags: probability

Consider the discrete distribution supported on $\mathbb{N},$ where the probability of getting $r$ equals $\frac{1}{e r!}.$ I can't seem to find its name (its sort of like a discrete version of the Gamma distribution).

Comment: How does this problem arise? (Needing to identify a name for a pmf,)

Comment: I found that this is the probability density (in large $n$ limit) for the number of fixed points of a random element in $S_n.$ It seemed obvious that this was a known distribution, but I blanked out for some reason.

Comment: Ah. Of course most readers here are unlikely to know that by $S_n$ you're referring to the symmetric group on $n$ symbols; that context could make your question more broadly useful, since if it were in your question a search could turn it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ has pmf

$P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$

Your function is a special case of that.

Comment: Poisson(1) occurs in all manner of situations.